# Starting points for creating a mysql database proxy

Tags: mysql

I'm not actually entirely sure if this is possible, but I'd like to build piece of software that behaves a lot like a proxy between a client and a mysql server.

Essentially, I want this software to expose a connection string the same way a normal mysql database would, and listen to the same port.  When it receives traffic (mysql queries), it would apply some modifications to them *before* handing them off to the actual mysql database.

Is this possible? If so, where would I even start in building this? Finally, are there any recommendations on how to do this properly?

I'm also open to exploring off-the-shelf options if something like this already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there two or three such software packets available, but usually you use this two split the incoming packages after rules to different servers.

It is in the begining , sowhat difficult to configure, but there a a lot of tutorials

https://proxysql.com/  or https://github.com/mysql/mysql-proxy

Comment: "MySQL Proxy is a simple program that sits between your client and MySQL server(s) ... query analysis, query filtering and modification ..."

This looks to be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm thankful I don't need to reinvent the wheel. Thanks!